# Regarding Population of Grid data with Ajax Polling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Map which contains the status information as a value for a object.The Ajax should poll the map and update the status on the grid.I am facing issue in updating the same.
The code snippet I am using is:

```
setInterval(
  $.post("./listStatus.action", {
     method: "getStatus",
  }, function( data, success ) {
        if ( success == "success" ) {        
           var rowsIds = statusGrid.getDataIDs();
           console.log("Row Ids:"+rowsIds);
        for(var i=0;i<data.statusList.length;i++){
          var rowData=statusGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',data.statusList[i].rowID);
          rowData["Status"] =data.statusList[i].Status;
          statusGrid.jqGrid('setRowData', data.statusList[i].rowID, rowData);
          } 

      }
  }),5000);
```

On first call its able to show the data however in second call onwards it gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
Can anybody help me out how to implement the use case and how to resolve the issue as i am new to JS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question exactly but, it might get you going.  In my experience with jqGrid my automatic grid refreshes looked something like this.

If my HTML looked like this:

```
<div style="margin: 10px;">
    <table id="custGrid"></table>
    <div id="ptoolbar"></div>
    <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;"></div>
</div>
```

The the javascript has this:

```
var grid = $("#custGrid");
jQuery("#custGrid").jqGrid({ ... });
```

when I refresh the data in the grid I would do something like this:

```
jQuery("#custGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: { filters: postobj }, page: 1 });
jQuery("#custGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

The trigger reload tells jqGrid to fetch new data based on the revised grid parameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can you suggest me if i want to use a setInterval method how i can implement the above as refresh is not working in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` takes a function as first parameter :

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.post("./listStatus.action", {
        method: "getStatus",
    }, function (data, success) {
        if (success == "success") {
            var rowsIds = statusGrid.getDataIDs();
            console.log("Row Ids:" + rowsIds);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.statusList.length; i++) {
                var rowData = statusGrid.jqGrid('getRowData', data.statusList[i].rowID);
                rowData["Status"] = data.statusList[i].Status;
                statusGrid.jqGrid('setRowData', data.statusList[i].rowID, rowData);
            }
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

I haven't checked the rest of your code.